# What is meant by ‘local structure’ of proteins?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure

The EBI/EMBL training course includes the following definition of [Secondary structure of proteins](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/courses/biomacromolecular-structures/proteins/levels-of-protein-structure-primary/levels-of-protein-structure-secondary/):

> Secondary structure refers to the regular, **local** structure of the protein backbone, stabilized by intramolecular and sometimes intermolecular hydrogen bonding of amide groups.

What does the word ”**local**” mean in this case?

Is there anything that is *not* local in the case of protein structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***‘Local’** appears to be a term that is used in relation to the structure of proteins to distinguish specific small parts of it from the overall structure, which in this context appears to be termed the **‘global’*** structure.

I write ‘appears’, because I had not met it before, but I draw this conclusion from a section of a review in the journal, *Computers*, entitled [*Local Structure Comparison of Proteins*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0065245806680054):

> Starting from the 3D coordinates of the atoms in a protein…
> *global structure comparison* can determine the similarity of two complete protein structures.…
>  However, a protein’s global
> structure does not always determine its function.…
>    For this
> reason there has been increased interest in *local structure
> comparison* to identify structural similarity between parts of
> proteins.

One does not, in my experience, encounter this term in definitions of secondary structure in general biochemistry texts, which might use something more generally comprehensible like *“sections of the overall structure”*. Although EBI/EMBL is an authoritative institution, its staff tend to have expertise in research and computational work rather than education.